# How check a checkbox and show a input field in jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have made a function which returns `JSON` response and the values coming from this `response` is showed in the `input fields`.

this is `table` when I clicked the `edit` button. it sends a request to the `master_get_items` file and receives the `response`

**Table image**

[image]
**Response for ID No 4**

```
    {
  "ID": "4",
  "item_title": "slaePrice",
  "item_price": "99999.99",
  "big_pic": "front/images/items/dcba27227bc0f165910a5ba5979a3811.png",
  "item_description": "<p>dsfsdfs</p>\r\n",
  "sale_price": "23",
  "status": "enabled"
}
```

this response has a `sale_price` of `23`. so I made an `if` statement in `JQuery` if the `sale_price` value is greater then `0`. then check the checkbox and show the `input field` which works well.

but when I click the `edit` button of `ID no 5` in the response the value of `sale_price` is `null` but still the `checkbox` is checked and the `input field` is shown.

**Response for ID No 5**

```
{
  "ID": "5",
  "item_title": "asd",
  "item_price": "2.00",
  "big_pic": "front/images/items/d73a11ab42e2974df57612e8a0d7ce01.png",
  "item_description": "<p>adsfsadfsdfsdfsd</p>\r\n",
  "sale_price": null,
  "status": "enabled"
}
```

**The if statement which I have write**

```
  var sale_product = "";
sale_product = outputData.sale_price;
if (sale_product !== "") {
    $("#Editsale").prop("checked", true);
    $("#EditsalePrice").show();
    modal.find("input#Editsale_price").val(outputData.sale_price);
} else if (sale_product == "") {
    $("#Editsale").prop("checked", false);
    $("#EditsalePrice").hide();
}
```

**HTML code for Checkbox and input fields**

```
    <div class="col-md-3">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="Sale">Product On Sale?</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="Editsale" name="Editsale" class="checkbox checkboxsize">
   </div>
</div>
<div id="EditsalePrice" style="display:none">
   <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="">Sale Price</label>
         <input type="text" name="Editsale_price" id="Editsale_price" placeholder="Enter Product Sale Price" class="form-control">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**let see image for ID no 4**

[image]

**let see image for ID no 5**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thnx to all of you. I have correct it by doing `if(sale_product != null)` and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `if (sale_product !== "")` with `if (sale_product) {` and remove the `else if`. This check if the value is not `false`, `null`, `undefined`, empty string, 0 or `NaN`

Comment: Are you sure that #Editsale and #EditsalePrice are unique id on page?

Comment: thnx bro. I have write if(sale_product != null) and it works. thnx for helping

Answer (score 0):

try adding in `!empty(sale_product) {` to your if statement

Comment: you could also try `if(sale_product != null)`

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.